# gSoap example is not compiling

Tags: c++, soap, wsdl, gsoap

I am trying to build my first gSoap application. Even the calc example given wouldn't compile for me. I followed the readme file, and did the following:

1. converted the wsdl to a header with the provided tool (`wsdl2h -s -o calc.h http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/calc.wsdl`)
2. Used `soapcpp2` with the generated `calc.h` (`soapcpp2 -i calc.h`)
3. Created a new project, added a "soap" directory, and copied the following files there: `calc.nsmap, soapC.cpp, soapcalcProxy.h, soapH.h, soapStub.h, stdsoap2.h, stdsoap2.cpp`
4. Wrote this piece of code:

   ```
   #include "soap/soapcalcProxy.h"
   #include "soap/calc.nsmap"

   int main()
   {
       calcProxy service;
       double result;
       if (service.add(1.0, 2.0, result) == SOAP_OK)
           std::cout << "The sum is " << result << std::endl;
       else
           service.soap_stream_fault(std::cerr);
   }
   ```
5. Tried to compile

   ```
   make all 
   Building file: ../soap/soapC.cpp
   Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
   g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"soap/soapC.d" -MT"soap/soapC.d" -o "soap/soapC.o" "../soap/soapC.cpp"
   ../soap/soapC.cpp: In function ‘int soap_out_SOAP_ENV__Reason(soap*, const char*, int, const SOAP_ENV__Reason*, const char*)’:
   ../soap/soapC.cpp:914:48: error: too many arguments to function ‘int soap_set_attr(soap*, const char*, const char*)’
   ../soap/stdsoap2.h:2384:27: note: declared here
   make: *** [soap/soapC.o] Error 1
   ```

It complains about wrong number of arguments  *in a generated file*. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your are mixing 2 differents release of gSOAP :
 1. the code generator `soapcpp2`
 2. the include file `soap/stdsoap2.h` (it's not a generated file but an part of gSOAP)

If you installed gsoap as a package, the include file should be in /usr/include. Otherwise you should add "-I [gSOAP include]" to the compile command and "-L [gSOAP lib]" to the link command.

I was able to build your main.cpp with the following commands

```
 mkdir soap
 wsdl2h -s -o soap/calc.h http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/calc.wsdl
 soapcpp2 -i soap/calc.h -d soap
 g++ -o calc main.cpp soap/soapC.cpp soap/soapcalcProxy.cpp -lgsoap++
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, I also discovered this myself recently.